# Convert Int64 to binary and back?

Tags: .net-4.0

Is there a way to convert Int64 to binary and back to Int64?

Comment: How do you want to represent it? Big-endian or low-endian?

Comment: Whatever, I just need a way to store datetime in binary and retrieve it back, so I thought about storing it's ticks.

Comment: In the title you say 64, in the text 16 bit. Which one is it ?

Comment: @DarkDust typing mistake, fixed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
var bytes = BitConverter.GetBytes(long);
var value = BitConverter.ToInt64(bytes, 0);
```

Comment: If you need a to convert to endianess that's different from your machine's, use [Jon Skeet's MiscUtil](http://www.yoda.arachsys.com/csharp/miscutil/) `EndianBitConverter`.

Comment: @HuBeZa thanks for your comment, I am sure it will be helpful in the future, and if not me then for others.

Answer (score 1):

if string formatting is what you need:

```
Convert.ToString(someInt64, 2);
Convert.ToUInt64("101010", 2);
```

Answer (score 0):

Similar to HuBeZa's answer, this converts type `long` to string:

```
Convert.ToString(Convert.ToInt64(myLongInt), 2);
```